# Should we include SDL in product name tags?

Tags: discussion

Should we be using SDL in other product names for tagging

For example: sdl-media-manager or media-manager, sdl-smart-target or smart-target

My personal feeling is we should use synonyms to handle both cases? What does everyone think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synonyms would be the best to make sure we handle both indeed.

I think SDL marketing would like us to use SDL in the names, but I think most of the community members would prefer shorter tags and omit SDL.

Comment: +1. Short names worked on StackOverflow. We can even go shorter for versions (e.g. `2009` for `SDL Tridion 2009`). I have seen newer customers confuse product with company name and call Tridion simply SDL. So +1 to synonyms along with using the correct names in actual questions and tag descriptions.

Comment: Definitely In with droppi g the SDL bit from the tags but I do wonder a little bit if shortening Tridon 2011 to just 2011 is the correct thing to do. What happens if we do that and 6 weeks from now we have Tridion 2013 and User Experiance Manager 2013, what would the tag 2013 be related to othat case?

Comment: I would say product + version without SDL to avoid confusion, where the suite is Tridion so "Tridion 2011", "SmartTarget 2011 SP2", "Media Manager 2.3"